# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') observed only when tests are run in Monitor mode of Postman

Tags: postman, typeerror, monitor

I have a simple GET http request which when executed in postman individually or in a runner does not give any error, however when it is executed in a Monitor it always throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') error. Below id the Response.

```json
[
 {
        "id": "13",
        "description": "Visitor1"
    },
    {
        "id": "14",
        "description": "Visitor2"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "description": "Visitor3"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "description": "Visitor4"
    }
]
```

And this is my Test section

```js
if (responseCode.code == 200) {
    let jsonData = pm.response.json();
    console.log(jsonData);
    let Id = JSON.parse(jsonData[1].id);
    console.log(JSON.parse(Id));
    pm.environment.set('Test_Id', Id);
    pm.environment.set('Test_Description', jsonData[1].description);
}
```

it is giving error whenever it tries to read the Id value from the response, however this happens only when it is executed in the Monitor mode and not individually or in a runner. What might be causing this?

Reading the articles I have tried setting logs and defining the variable using Const, let and var but it has not worked.

Comment: Do you have log when running by Monitor?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17: yes this appears only in the console logs of the monitor and does not fail the test case, however it fails the monitor run. This appears in the console logs _TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')_

Comment: It means the response doesn't have structure as you expect. Could you log the response before `if-else` block?

Comment: This is the change you asked

let jsonData = pm.response.json();
console.log(jsonData);

if (responseCode.code == 200) {    
let Id = JSON.parse(jsonData[1].id);
console.log(JSON.parse(Id));    
pm.environment.set('Imron_Id',Id);
pm.environment.set('Imron_Description', jsonData[1].description);
}

and this is what got logged in the console log

[ { id: '13', description: 'Visitor1' },
  { id: '14', description: 'Visitor2' },
  { id: '15', description: 'Visitor3' },
  { id: '16', description: 'Visitor4' } ]
14

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.
The problem was that in some cases, the Monitor execution might be faster or slower than the individual or runner execution, leading to timing-related issues. Make sure the response is fully received before accessing its properties. You can add a delay or use `pm.test` with assertions to ensure the response is complete.

Use setTimeout(function(){}, [number]);

where number is time in milliseconds.